# SQL Server Maintenance plan issue

Tags: sql-server

I have configured maintenance plan for full backup. Backup file is generating. But, It is not showing in history.

[image]

Comment: That's weird, and the duration is 0:00 too. Maybe it's related with your syspolicy_purge_history job. Have you tried to execute it manually ?

Comment: Hi Vercelli, I'm using 2005 server. I think it was introduced in 2008.

Comment: I don't know about that, Have you tried to execute the full backup maintenance plan manually?

Comment: @@Vercelli-----------Yes, I tried. Actually I scheduled everyday at 9:30 PM. Maintenance plan is running daily and backup file also generating. But, history is not available in maintenance plan as well as job history.

Comment: Hi guys, Finally issue has been resolved after start the job manually. There was no use to start manually maintenance plan

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue has been resolved after start the job manually.